# Select Person without record in Table 2 or records do not match criteria in Table 2

Tags: sql-server, select, stored-procedures

This is related to a SQL Server stored procedure I am working on.

*Problem to solve:* Select a record from table 1 when a record with matching ID does not exist in table 2 or does not meet expected conditions

This example is what I am trying to do with names of the tables changed.

Two Tables: **Person**, **Stuff**

Select Person.Name

Conditions:

1. If no Stuff record
2. if no Stuff between '7/1/18' and '6/30/19' and Stuff.Status is not 'Draft'

Example of Data:

```
TABLE Person

Person.PersonID, Person.Name

1, Frank
2, Tom
3, Barb

TABLE Stuff

Stuff.StuffID, Stuff.PersonID, Stuff.CreatedDate, Stuff.Status

1, 1, '7/30/18', 'Draft'
2, 2, '8/14/18', 'Submitted'
```

Expected Query Results

```
1. Frank
2. Barb
```

I can't figure out how to properly handle the conditions mentioned above to show the correct result. I tried to find an answer matching what I needed, but nothing seemed to fit exactly.

**~~~ Update with working solution ~~~**

With the help of Brian and Eric, I was able to find what I was doing wrong. My conditions confused me into thinking I needed multiple sets of conditions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Person.Name
FROM Person
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Stuff
    WHERE
    Person.PersonID = Stuff.PersonID
    AND Stuff.CreatedDate >= '2018-07-01'
    AND Stuff.CreatedDate <= '2019-06-30'
    AND Stuff.Status <> 'Draft'
)
```

Basically this made it so anything that didn't fit the expected criteria was returned, which was what I was going for but confused myself into thinking I needed more.

Comment: Think about it in reverse: write a query that gives you the PersonID values that you do NOT want, and then use that as a sub-query for a NOT IN clause.

Comment: @Brian Thank you, I'll give that a try.

Comment: @Brian your comment about starting with what I didn't want to see and then use it for a NOT IN clause helped me get to a working solution. I didn't use NOT IN, but I did write the NOT EXISTS select statement based on the results I did not want to see. I was definitely thinking about it in the wrong way. Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome.  That's what this site is all about.  Frankly, I think the "not exists" approach is better in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this gets what you're after, `NOT EXISTS` for your conditions.

```
SELECT
  p.Name
FROM
  Person AS p
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM Stuff AS s
  WHERE
    s.PersonId = p.PersonId
    AND s.CreatedDate >= '2018-07-01'
    AND s.CreatedDate <= '2019-06-30'
    AND s.Status <> 'Draft'
);
```

**Edit:** I trimmed the answer down to the code that worked for the OP, based on edits to the question and comments below.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this and mark it the answer if I can get it working.

Comment: Eric, NOT Exists was definitely the answer. If you update your answer with only NOT EXISTS, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. You helped me a great deal to realize what I was doing wrong and deserve the credit for getting me there. I've updated the question with the working solution. Your mentioning of redundancy made me closer evaluate the conditions I really needed. Thanks Again!

Comment: @San, I edited the answer based on your edits & comment. Glad it helped!